# layout items alignment not centered

Tags: android, xml, layout

i want to align text items at center, in the android studio layout preview it is showing correctly but not showing correctly on device.

i am unable to insert picture due to reputation problem.

here are the links

http://checker.in/go/2155907 on device

http://checker.in/go/2155908 layout preview in Android Studio

here is the layout xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.testing.myapplication.Test">






<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lfriends"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Friends"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/friends"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lphotos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Photos"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/photos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblogs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Blogs"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blogs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your parent LinearLayout to have the following attributes and see if it works.  You may have to change your ConstraintLayout constraints based on where you want it:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    >
```